# How to only return the returned variables from PHP AJAX call?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have recently created an CMS system by following this guide:

http://requiremind.com/a-most-simple-php-mvc-beginners-tutorial/

However i am facing a problem with using AJAX calls from within my PHP pages. When sending a post request to a controller method the returned data includes the layout.php html data where all i really want is the echoed PHP variable.

layout.php file:

```
<?php
<DOCTYPE html><head>

    <title>Stack overflow question</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- pulls in the relevant page -->
    <?php require_once('routes.php'); ?>

  <body>

<html>
?>
```

routes.php file:

```
<?php
  function call($controller, $action) {
// require the file that matches the controller name
require_once('controllers/' . $controller . '_controller.php');

// create a new instance of the needed controller
switch($controller) {
  case 'pages':
    $controller = new PagesController();
  break;
  case 'controller':
    $controller = new controller();
  break;

}

// call the action
$controller->{ $action }();
  }

  // just a list of the controllers we have and their actions
  // we consider those "allowed" values
  $controllers = array('pages' => ['error'],
                   'controller' => ['getapostervariable', 'openpage']);

  // check that the requested controller and action are both allowed
  // if someone tries to access something else he will be redirected to the error action of the pages controller
  //checking if the controller variable is contained within the controllers array.
  if (array_key_exists($controller, $controllers)) {
  //checking to see if the action is available in the controllers array at the point of the controller key
if (in_array($action, $controllers[$controller])) {
  call($controller, $action);
    } else {
  call('pages', 'error');
}
  } else {
call('pages', 'error');
  }
 ?>
```

for example If i have a controller:

```
class controller{

   public static function openpage(){
      require_once(page.php);
   }

   public static function getapostedvariable(){
      require_once(page.php);
      $string = $_POST['string'];
      echo $string;
   }
}
```

and an AJAX request:

```
$.post("http://site/index.php?controller=controller&action=getapostedvariable",
{
    string: "hello there"
},
function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
});
```

it returns the parent php page (layout.php which uses require_once to include my page with the ajax request) and my php variable $string within the body tags of that page.

I just want to know if it is possible to only receive the php variable in the ajax response / how I can do this?

Comment: where are you including layout.php ?

Comment: so layout.php includes routes.php which in turn includes my controller.php (which opens the required page), so layout.php->routes.php->controller.php->page.php(has the ajax request that is sent to a method on controller.php)

Comment: it follows the same structure as documented in the tutorial linked :)

Comment: replace `echo $string;` by `echo $string; return false;`

Comment: after any echo; if  you want to finish the ajax response just use die();

Comment: @Gonzalo.- this unfortunately does not resolve my issue as the html response data is before the outputted string, for example the ajax returns the layout.php page with my echoed variable inside the body tags of layout.php

Comment: have updated my question to hopefully provide more information - i believe its to do with the structure of my php files - the ajax is returning the parent php page data- if that makes any sense haha ...

Comment: Then separate your code - move your logic to reusable services/scripts, and let ajax and not-ajax requests go to different endpoints. Don't mix endpoint for ajax and non-ajax requests

Comment: @Gonzalo.- so write a seperate php script for my ajax requests to go to ?

Comment: yes. But if you need logic that apply for both,I'd suggest you to move that common logic to service files, or partial/template files if they are view-related

Comment: okay, great, thanks for the help :)